# Didn't receive mail sent from SMTP yet?

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I used a local Smtp server for sending mails to a register user email id.It is showing that mail has been because it created a .eml file in referenced PICKUP-DIRECTORY.This file has all details about the mail.but receiver yet didn't receive it even more than 10 minutes has benn passed since it was send.
Why so?

Thanks in advance.

---

OK.
This is the code.

```
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="userwizard" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/secretfiles/secret.aspx" runat="server" >
    <MailDefinition BodyFileName="register.txt" Subject="Registration Confirmation" From="amrit.enest@gmail.com" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: Did you actually send it? I mean is there some type of process that's supposed to pickup the `.eml` files and send them?

Comment: i think no there is not any such type of process.i just created a registration form using "creatuserwizard" property in asp like below and then did settings for smtp.it is generating the .eml file but there is no process to manipulate it.doesn't generation of .eml files means that mail has been sent?
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="userwizard" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/secretfiles/secret.aspx" runat="server" >
    <MailDefinition BodyFileName="register.txt" Subject="Registration Confirmation" From="amrit.enest@gmail.com" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>

Comment: Please do not place code in comments, I'm going to move the code to the question.

Comment: SMTP offers no guarantees about delivery time. It's a best effort protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1444046.aspx/1). Keep in mind that you need to set the `mailSettings` in your `web.config` and follow any of the other guidance. That should get it working for you.

Also this [article](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=33) shows you how to use Gmail as a relaying server.

Comment: I doubt that i didn't provide password of email anywhere(from where i have to send emails to registered users).?

Comment: @user1544975 Alright then you need to make sure you're allowed to relay off of the SMTP server - my guess is that's the issue.

Comment: @user1544975 This [article](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=33) should help you.